# After some period of time some symbols become bold Android 4-5

Tags: android, fonts, calligraphy

After some period of time, some symbols become bold on Android 4-5. We use custom font ubuntг and library Calligraphy.

This is the code we use to work with Calligrapy:

```
    @Override protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
      }

CalligraphyUtils.applyFontToTextView(this, TypefaceUtils.load(assets, App.UBUNTU_REGULAR_TYPEFACE))
```

This is how it looks

[image]

**UPDATE:**

After using standard Android [way](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html) everything become ok

Comment: post the code where you use `CalligraphyContextWrapper`

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know issue since 2017, the problem is "Probably" related to `Locale` settings. When your app goes background and foreground your device Locale changes and Calligraphy can't handle this so the symbols revert themselves.

Unfortunately the author is not good at tracking/fixing the issues, as you can see there are [110 open issues](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues)

[This](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/382) is the issue related to your problem, it's still open.